# Returning ajax data loop for ion-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I have a loop with user id, name etc ... from a json, how to enter these data in a listview in ionic?
When I use the direct alert in javascript it works properly and returns users but when return on ng-repeat it just returns me one user.

must come from the list eg

user 1
user 2
user 3

...

can someone give me a light, I am very new in ionic and AngularJS, already thank you very much.

my ajax

```
$.ajax({

  type : 'POST',
  data : formula,
  url : 'http://localhost/melleve/mt.php',
  success : function(data){

  var retorno = JSON.parse(data);    

$.each(retorno, function(index, value) {

var nome = value.nome;
var id = value.id;

var cli = [ { nome: nome, id: id } ];

$scope.clientes = cli;

  });

  },

})


}
```

my ng-repeat

```
<ion-list>

        <ion-item ng-repeat="cli in clientes">

          <p>{{cli.nome}}</p>
          <p>{{cli.id}}</p>

        </ion-item>

       </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mixup `jQuery` code with `AngularJS`, that would messed up with angular digest system if you are modifying angular scope variables from jQuery(**specially asynchronously**). You will not get updated binding on view. Because anything runs up outside of angular world, angular digest system don't fire up digest cycle for it, resultant bindings won't get updated over the view.

You should use `$http` service to make ajax call, rather than mixing `$.ajax` with angular. So by using `$http` wrapper service you will get binding updated binding, as `$http` service method fires up digest cycle whenever ajax call `succeed/fail`

**Code**

```
$http.post('http://localhost/melleve/mt.php', formula).then(function(response) {
    var retorno = response.data;
    $.each(retorno, function(index, value) {
        var nome = value.nome;
        var id = value.id;
        var cli = [{
            nome: nome,
            id: id
        }];
        $scope.clientes = cli;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response friend, managed to solve the problem by removing all variables within the ajax and including the lower JSON.parse the $ scope was so

var retorno = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.clientes = retorno;

Comment: @WevertonSouza i didn't thought why parsing is needed there.. why don't send JSON data from server?(no, then do this, will save your effort in future). Can you do upvote please, if mine answer does helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot and worked here, thank you.